# Converting Java to MIPS - Outputs the user input and the whole list instead of list location

Tags: java, list, output, mips

Okay so now all I get is all the numbers I enter and everything that is contained with in the list. Only supposed to get the user input and the location in the list where the number is.

```
                    .data
list:       .word 5
        .word 7
        .word 4
        .word 6
        .word 3
        .word 8
        .word 2
        .word 9
        .word 0
        .word 30
        .word 31
        .word 39
        .word 32
        .word 38
        .word 33
        .word 37
        .word 34
        .word 36
        .word 35
        .word 20
        .word 21
        .word 29
        .word 22
        .word 28
        .word 23
        .word 27
        .word 24
        .word 26
        .word 25
        .word 10
        .word 11
        .word 19
        .word 12
        .word 18
        .word 13
        .word 17
        .word 14
        .word 16
        .word 15
        .word 1         # last array element
        .word -1            # not part of array
prompt1:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter an array element: "
prompt2:    .asciiz "\nPlease enter a search target: "
space:  .asciiz " "
nfound: .asciiz "\nThe target was not found."
found:  .asciiz "\nThe target was found at array location "

        .text
        .globl main
main:       add $t0, $zero, 39  # [main]
        add $t1, $zero, $zero   #
        addi $t2, $zero, 39 #
        addi $t3, $zero, 39 #
        add $t4, $zero, $zero   #
        add $t5, $zero, $zero   #
        add $t6, $zero, $zero   #
#       add $t7, $zero, $zero   #
        la $t8, list

read:       addi $v0, $zero, 4  # [read]
        la $a0, prompt1     #
        syscall
        addi $v0, $zero, 5  #
        syscall
        sll $t7, $t0, 2     #
        add $t9, $t8, $t7
        sw $v0, 0($t9)
        addi $t0, $t0, 1        #
        ble $t0, $t2, read  #

        add $t0, $zero, $zero   #

search:     add $t1, $zero, $zero
search2:    lw $t4, 0($t8)
        add $t5, $t4, 1
        lw $t5, 0($t8)
        sgt $t6, $t4, $t5
        sw $t5, 0($t8)
        add $t5, $t4, 1
        sw $t4, 0($t8)
        add $t1, $t1, 1
        blt $t1, $t3, search2
        sub $t3, $t3, 1
        add $t0, $t0, 1
        blt $t0, $t2, search

        add $t0, $zero, $zero

print:      addi $v0, $zero, 1  # [print]
        sll $t7, $t0, 2     #
        add $t9, $t8, $t7
        lw $a0, 0($t9)
        syscall
        addi $v0, $zero, 4  #
        la $a0, space       #
        syscall
        addi $t0, $t0, 1        #
        ble $t0, $t2, print #

end:        addi $v0, $zero, 10 # [end]
        syscall
```

Java Code:

```
package javaapplication15;
    import java.io.*;

    public class CIS2233StarterCode2Java {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader kbd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    int [] list = {5,7,4,6,3,8,2,9,0,20,21,29,22,28,23,27,24,26,25,30,31,39,32,38,33,37,34,36,35,10,11,19,12,18,13,17,14,16,15,1};
    String prompt1 = "\nPlease enter an array element: ";
    String prompt2 = "\nPlease enter a search target: ";
    String space = " ";
    String nfound = "\nThe target was not found.";
    String found = "\nThe target was fount at array location ";
    int t0 = 0;
    int t1 = 0;
    int t2 = 39;
    int t3 = 39;
    int t4;
    int t5;
    int t6;
    int a0;
    int v0;
    // address calculation register t7
    // base address of array register t8
    // address calculation register t9
    do {
        System.out.print (prompt1);
        v0 = Integer.parseInt(kbd.readLine());
        list [t0] = v0;
        t0 ++;
    } while (t0 < t2);
    t0 = 0;
    do {
        t1 = 0;
        do {
            t4 = list [t1];
            t5 = list [t1 + 1];
            if (t4 > t5) {
                list [t1 + 1] = t4;
                list [t1] = t5;
            }
            t1 ++;
        } while (t1 < t3);
        t3 --;
        t0 ++;
    } while (t0 < t2);
    t0 = 0;
    do {
        a0 = list [t0];
        System.out.print (a0);
        System.out.print (space);
        t0 ++;
    } while (t0 <= t2);
        }
        }
```

Example of the output: 5 7 4 6 3 8 2 9 0 30 31 39 32 38 33 37 34 36 35 20 21 29 22 28 23 27 24 26 25 10 11 19 12 18 13 17 14 16 15 5

Comment: Someone can help me figure out the problem with the user prompt that keeps displaying. If you actually read you will see I asked how come it is looping back through, "When I go to run it, all I get is the prompt. Supposed to look through the list and find if the number is there." Wanna try and rethink how you stated that? I absolutely mentioned what my problem is and where I need help. Also, did I say solve it for me? NO! I would like help solving it. What do you think I am doing? Just posting and leaving? I am testing the code still.

Comment: 20 views and 0 help, come on and just help me out here. Point out what is going wrong. Now it is replacing the first number with 780 and adding the user prompted number to the end

Comment: just not getting any help am i? I am asking exactly what I need help on and provided the things i needed to and still no replies. kinda rediculous considering this is a site for programmers to help each other and yet here is one asking for help and all i get is nothing. Why? Cuz my reputation is 29 or just don't like my question, shouldn't be the reason to do so.